# Why does coNP⊆NP∖P imply that the polynomial hierarchy collapses?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, np

I was looking for some information on 1-in-3 SAT and came across [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.02821), last updated 9 days ago, which claims that the Polynomial Time Hierarchy collapses "to the level above P=NP". That's quite exciting if you ask me, although I don't have the toolkit to understand the actual proof. My question is about something much simpler.

Specifically, in the abstract on arxiv, the author writes,

> Our proof shows the structure formerly known as the Polynomial
>   Hierarchy collapses to the level above P=NP. That is, we show that
>   coNP⊆NP∖P.

Could anyone help me understand why these two statements are equivalent?

Comment: Because $\mathrm{P} \subseteq \mathrm{coNP}$, we cannot have $\mathrm{coNP} \subseteq \mathrm{NP} \setminus \mathrm{P}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the claim is more commonly written as $coNP \subseteq NP/poly$, but that of course does not immediately answer your question.

The fact that this implies that the polynomial hierarchy collapses is shown in Theorem 2 here:

Chee-Keng Yap. Some consequences of non-uniform conditions on uniform
classes. *Theoretical Computer Science*, 26:287–300, 1983. doi:10.1016/
0304-3975(83 ) 90020-8

If I understand correctly, $coNP \subseteq NP/poly$ is shown to be equivalent to $coNP/poly = NP/poly$ (unnamed corollary on page 292), and this would then imply $\Pi_3 = \Sigma_3$ (Theorem 2), implying collapse of the further hierarchy. For an actual proof, if you have access to the paper, I'll refer you there, I am not familiar enough with it to attempt an explanation now.

On an unrelated note, I believe the paper you are citing to be **incorrect** (but that would probably warrant a separate question?)

Comment: you know, I kind of thought something was fishy when I couldn't find anyone else talking about this paper online -- but your answer makes sense regardless of the paper's overall validity, so thanks.

Answer (score 4):

> [...] the structure formerly known as the Polynomial Hierarchy collapses to the level above $\text{P}=\text{NP}$.

This claim makes no sense.  If $\text{P}=\text{NP}$, then the whole polynomial hierarchy is equal to $\text{P}$ and there is no level above that.

> That is, we show that $\text{co-NP}\subseteq\text{NP}\setminus{P}$.

$\text{co-NP}\subseteq\text{NP}\setminus{P}$ is unconditionally false, since $\text{P}\subseteq\text{co-NP}$ (and $\mathrm{P}\neq\emptyset)$.

I wouldn't recommend spending any time on this paper.

Comment: *I wouldn't recommend spending any time on this paper.* Agreed.

Comment: Now that I think about it, your statement "co-NP⊆NP∖P is unconditionally false, since P⊆co-NP" makes a lot of sense -- thanks for the advice that I don't look into the paper any further. I guess I assumed papers on arXiv were peer reviewed to some extent, but maybe they're not.

Comment: @JoelMiller ArXiv isn't peer-reviewed at all. Papers that are posted to ArXiv may subsequently be submitted to journals and peer-reviewed (e.g., all my ArXiv papers), but anyone who has posting rights to ArXiv can post whatever they want there.

Comment: I'm not an expert on the subject area of this paper and I don't know or know of the author. On the one hand, [user53293's explanation](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/110891/9550) that "$\mathrm{NP\setminus P}$ is supposed to be $\mathrm{NP/poly}$ is somewhat convincing. But, still, it would be very strange for somebody who worked in that field to consistently make that mistake. As soon as you have a high-school understanding of what set difference is, and if you know circuit complexity, it's obvious that "slash poly" and "minus polytime" refer to two completely different concepts.

Comment: @David Richerby I simply think that the author meaning NP/poly is the only explanation for the claims and "proofs" in the remainder of the paper. I fully agree that someone in the field should know better. And this is far from the only issue with the paper.